# Multiple Users on Single Machine for MS Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, license, licensing

Some old information *seems* to imply that Microsoft Office Home and Business 2010 is licensed for a *single* user, but I'm not sure this is actually so.  When I read the Microsoft License Terms [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-software-license-terms-for-microsoft-office-2010-HA101817777.aspx), it seems to imply that the software is actually licensed per device and an infinite number of users can access MS Office Home and Business 2010 on that single device as long as *only one* of them uses it at a time.

Am I right in assuming that a primary-user is legally allowed to install MS Office Home and Business 2010 on a single family PC for her/his business use and let her/his dependents take turns using the software for fun, college and primary/secondary school when the primary-user is not working?

Comment: You are right. I'm commenting because it's too short for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Microsoft licenses say you can install on **two computers** one *desktop* and one *laptop*. Multiple users **cannot** use it at the same time however, one user at a time. Many users on one computer can use the software, but many users on many computers **can't.**

For full **MSFT** EULAs search ***'Microsoft EULA [PRODUCT NAME]'*** on Google or Bing.

Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, that's Fair Use, other people can use soft at your PC ( of course at your approval). Business version of Office doesn't have usage restrictions (except uranium enrichment, yada yada, AFAIK USA national safety & export laws apply here)